# Adding Object in Array PyMongo

Tags: python, pymongo

How do I achieve a structure like following in Python?

[image]

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to demonstrate `$push`:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client  = MongoClient()
db = client.test_db
movies = db.movies

inserted_id = movies.insert_one({
    'name': 'Movie 1',
    'reviews': []
}).inserted_id


movies.update_one({'_id': inserted_id}, {
    '$push': {
        'reviews': [
            {
                'listing_id': '1',
                'reviewer_id': 'r1'
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Output from mongo console:

```
> db.movies.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ef0fb38642f75302be0c3f6"),
        "name" : "Movie 1",
        "reviews" : [
                [
                        {
                                "listing_id" : "1",
                                "reviewer_id" : "r1"
                        }
                ]
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! I only had to modify your reviews array from [[obj],[obj]] to [obj,obj]