# How to store array of objects in MongoDB from django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am using MongoDB as a database for my project and I want to store a list of the dictionary as an array of objects in an object in MongoDB from Django. For Eg. {"id":1,"products":[{...},{...},{...},{...}..]}  how do I define my model and how to query this. please help

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521069/adding-object-in-array-pymongo/62521318#62521318) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Object in Array PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521069/adding-object-in-array-pymongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) to start with maybe, it's database connector for MongoDB that uses the default Django ORM.
So you will define your models just like you do with mysql, sqlite, etc. But it enables some extra features.

Comment: I looked about djongo and was able to connect and make basic crud operations using orm. But I am confused about which field to use while creating the model to store list of dictionary. I was thinking of ManyToMany field but it does not help me in this case. I also read somewhere that django ORM only works best with relational database. I thought using pymongo but wanted to see that will ORM work here which will make things easier.

Comment: There's Embeded Fields that allow for storage of "arrays"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to store using ArrayField and EmbeddedField of Djongo

Comment: hello @Shivam could you please give an example? I know it's a long shot, but still :)

Comment: @Ashik, I posted an example here which might help you, not sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206433/djongo-arrayfield-item-is-not-subscriptable/63206828#63206828

Comment: @FelixEklöf Thanks